# Cannot change page properly in Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to change from a home page (ie localhost.com) to a another page (localhost.com/listing). The app builds properly but when I try to change the page, nothing happens.

I have followed mainly the tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6ipgij-AUw.

Here is my full app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ListingsComponent } from './listings/listings.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListingsComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'listing',
        component: ListingsComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  btnClick = function () {
    this.router.navigate('/listing');
  };

}
```

I am not sure whether the btnClick function is in the right place. I got the partial solution of this Q&A board but not sure its in the correct position. I have checked the listings component is working correctly by using . It says "listings works!" but still does so from the same home page (ideally this should be a blank white page with "listings works!", eg no nav-bar).

How should I route to a new page properly (ie no trace of the home page in /listing)? I cannot understand why this is happening because the listings.component.html does not include anything from the homepage.

For more information see: https://github.com/gf1721/directoryapp.

Comment: Hey this is extensively covered in the angular docs and they are easy to read https://angular.io/guide/router. Follow along there. The button is in the wrong place. It needs to be on a components .ts file, not in app module.

Comment: Programming is often much harder in reality than just reading a tutorial

Comment: Your question is literally, how do I do routing in angular. It's not like a unique question. Follow the docs and you'll see.

Comment: There does seem to be a lot of nuances though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how large you are planning on making this application, you are better off with creating an routing module.

**Step 1:**

This will generate an app-routing module for you in your src/app folder.

```
ng g m app-routing
```

**Step 2:**

Open your app-routing module and import all of the components you want to be able to navigate too as well as routermodule and routes.

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
```

**Step: 3**

Add a constant with the routes setup:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
];
```

**Step 4**

Add your routes to your imports and then export the router module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
```

**Step 5**

Now in your template html file you can do the follow:

```
<button type="button" routerLink="/home">Go home</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And the content on "home" will appear where router-outlet is.

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to avoid the <router-outlet> bit

Comment: Is there a specific reason why? It will be difficult for your app to scale if you don't have an app-routing setup, and if you want to do it the "proper" way

Comment: Im rebuilding it to try and use router-outlet now

Answer (score 1):

Change

**From**

```
 btnClick = function () {
   this.router.navigate('/listing');
};
```

**To**

```
btnClick () : void {
   this.router.navigate('/listing');
}
```

Also the button should be on the component, you are placing it inside the module, which will anyway not work.

Place the button on the app component and bind the logic to navigate on the button click as mentioned above

Comment: should there be a ; on the end of the to section?

Comment: This is not the right answer and not the problem with your code. Yes you should change it to this format as that's how you write typescript, but that's not your issue as far as functionality.

Comment: Please mark your edits so comments don't lose their meaning @Sajeetharan

Comment: @Zachscs yeah you are right! on the first look the issue i found was the typescript format